# SQL query with GROUP BY and HAVING

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have a little problem in mi project, i'm trying to make a query on a single table but I'm not succeeding.
The table is this:

```
CREATE TABLE PARTITA(
COD_SFIDA VARCHAR (20) PRIMARY KEY,
DATA_P DATE NOT NULL, 
RISULTATO CHAR (3) NOT NULL,
COD_DECK_IC VARCHAR (15),
COD_DECK_FC VARCHAR (15),
COD_EVT VARCHAR (15),
TAG_USR_IC VARCHAR (15),
TAG_USR_FC VARCHAR (15),
CONSTRAINT CHECK_RISULTATO CHECK (RISULTATO='0-0' OR RISULTATO='0-1' OR RISULTATO='1-0' OR RISULTATO='1-1'),
CONSTRAINT FK8 FOREIGN KEY (COD_DECK_IC, TAG_USR_IC) REFERENCES DECK (COD_DECK, TAG_USR) ON DELETE CASCADE,
CONSTRAINT FK17 FOREIGN KEY (COD_DECK_FC, TAG_USR_FC) REFERENCES DECK (COD_DECK, TAG_USR) ON DELETE CASCADE,
CONSTRAINT FK9 FOREIGN KEY (COD_EVT) REFERENCES TORNEO (COD_EVENTO) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

I would like to view the most used deck by each user.

this is the query I tried to do:

```
SELECT  P.COD_DECK_FC, P.TAG_USR_FC, COUNT(P.COD_DECK_FC)
FROM PARTITA P
GROUP BY P.TAG_USR_FC, P.COD_DECK_FC
UNION
SELECT  P.COD_DECK_IC, P.TAG_USR_IC, COUNT(P.COD_DECK_IC)
FROM PARTITA P
GROUP BY P.TAG_USR_IC, P.COD_DECK_IC
/
```

But I would like to view just the most used deck by each user and don't all the decks and how many times users used them.
How can I do?

I would like the query to show the tag_usr and the cod_deck that is used the most for all of this for each user
eg:

```
cod_deck         tag_usr  count(cod_deck)
-------------  ----------- --------------
1                 A1BE2      5
2                 AE3NF      6
5                 FNKJD      3
```

instead the previious query returns to me:

```
cod_deck         tag_usr  count(cod_deck)
-------------  ----------- --------------
1                 A1BE2      5
2                 AE3NF      6
5                 FNKJD      3
2                 A1BE2      2
1                 AE3NF      3
```

I just want that the query show me the users A1BE2 and AE3NF just one time, because the query have to select the most used deck of each user.

Comment: When you added the SQL tag, you were shown a message that suggested that you also add a tag for the specific DBMS you're using, because syntax and functionality is different between them. Why did you ignore that suggestion? You've just made it take longer to get an answer, and risked wasting the time of people who try to help by writing one only to find out it won't work for your particular DBMS. Please [edit] your post and add the appropriate DBMS tag. (I've removed the unnecessary SHOUTING from the title for you, but I can't add the tag.)

Comment: done, sry for the inconvenience

Comment: What happened to "FNKJD"?

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to select a field that you're counting.  Try something like this:

```
SELECT  P.COD_DECK_FC, P.TAG_USR_FC, COUNT(P.COD_SFIDA)
FROM PARTITA P
GROUP BY P.COD_DECK_FC, P.TAG_USR_FC
UNION
SELECT  P.COD_DECK_IC, P.TAG_USR_IC, COUNT(P.COD_SFIDA)
FROM PARTITA P
GROUP BY P.COD_DECK_IC, P.TAG_USR_IC
```

That will list all of the combinations of `COD_DECK_FC` and `TAG_USR_FC`
 and then number of times it appears in the table, and then do the same with `COD_DECK_IC` and `TAG_USR_IC`.  It's not clear to me from your question exactly what you want, but I know that you shouldn't put a field in COUNT if you're selecting it.

Answer (score 0):

If i *understand* correctly you need `subquery` with ranking function :

```
with t as (
       select *, row_number() over (partition by cod_deck order by count desc) Seq
       from (<union query>)
)

select *
from cte c
where seq = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want this:

```
with ct as (
      select P.COD_DECK_FC as deck, P.TAG_USR_FC as usr, COUNT(P.COD_DECK_FC) as cnt
      from partita p
      group by P.TAG_USR_FC, P.COD_DECK_FC
      union all
      select  P.COD_DECK_IC, P.TAG_USR_IC, COUNT(P.COD_DECK_IC)
      from partita P
      group by P.TAG_USR_IC, P.COD_DECK_IC
     )
select ct.*
from (select ct.*, 
             row_number() over (partition by usr order by cnt desc) as seqnum
      from ct
     ) ct
where seqnum = 1;
```

You can also shorten this using `grouping sets`:

```
select p.*
from (select coalesce(P.COD_DECK_FC, P.COD_DECK_IC) as deck,
             coalesce(P.TAG_USR_FC, P.TAG_USR_IC) as usr, 
             count(*) as cnt,
             row_number() over (partition by coalesce(P.TAG_USR_FC, P.TAG_USR_IC) order by count(*) desc) as seqnum
      from partita p
      group by grouping sets ( (P.TAG_USR_FC, P.COD_DECK_FC), P.TAG_USR_IC, P.COD_DECK_IC) )
     ) p
where seqnum = 1;
```